# Can't extract decimal number from array created with np.linspace in if statement

Tags: python-3.x, linspace

If I run the following code it does not recognize several of the numbers in the array, like `0.1`, even though it looks like `0.1` is in the array when it is printed.

```
import numpy as np

pH = 0.1

print(np.linspace(0.0, 2.9, num=30))

if pH in np.linspace(0.0, 2.9, num=30):
    print("it doesn't recognize 0.1")

pH = 0.3

if pH in np.linspace(0.0, 2.9, num=30):
    print('however it does recognize 0.3')
```

Output:

```
[0.  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 2.  2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8 2.9]
however, it does recognize 0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

This fault is mainly due to the fact that NumPy and Python are somewhat [finicky](https://0.30000000000000004.com) when it comes to storing, and consequently, comparing floating point integers.

We can see that python's `0.1` is actually:

```py
>>> print('{0:.20f}'.format(0.1))
0.10000000000000000555
```

while NumPy's `0.1` is actually:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print('{0:.20f}'.format(np.linspace(0.0, 2.9, num=30)[1])) # 0.1 in list
0.09999999999999999167
```

Therefore, to properly compare these, you can use the provided [math.isclose()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) or [numpy.isclose()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) (compares two lists):

```py
import math

# -- snip --

for num in np.linspace(0.0, 2.9, num=30):
    if math.isclose(0.1, num):
        print('detected!')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the value the numpy array is displaying is different than the actual value. Probably due to [floating point accuracy](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). If you want a way to get around this you could use a list comprehension.

```
import numpy as np

pH = 0.1

print(np.linspace(0.0, 2.9, num=30))

if pH in [round(x, 5) for x in np.linspace(0.0, 2.9, num=30)]:
    print("it does recognize 0.1")
```